# I get this error when trying to display a static image on blazor C#?

Tags: c#, html, image, blazor

//this is the error: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Rus/source/repos/TestProj/wwwroot/logoPng/test.png im not sure how to solve this issue..

```
<div>
        <h1>@imgName</h1>
        <h1>@img</h1>
        <div>
            <img src="@img" asp-append-version="true" style="width:400px;height:400px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    @code {
        string img = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\wwwroot\logoPng\test.png";
    }
```

Comment: Instead, use `string img = "//logoPng//test.png";`.

Comment: use a relaive link or you will have trouble with base href changes. so something like `./logoPng/test.png`

Comment: You shouldn't load the image from the local machine, but rather from your application itself. You can do that by following the other comments/answers which uses a relative approach.

Answer (score 0):

To access the file(s) from `wwwroot` folder,

```cs
string img = "//logoPng//test.png";
```

---

**References**

[Serve static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-static-files)